# How to Show a particular row first from a select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query results like below

```
name   id

a   2
b   3
c   7
h   9
i   1
```

i need to show the results like below 
Expected Result

```
name    id
c   7
a   2
b   3
h   9
i   1
```

The id field is Primarykey so based on that i want to show this

so far i tried with order by but it only give the option to order like decenting or acenting.

Please help me to do this

I had done something like below

```
create procedure proc1
@id int;
begin 

select name,id from tablname order by id 

end
```

I had also tried like but it also fails . Please help me to solve this

Comment: Sorry, but i have absolutely no idea what rule you are using for the ordering. Could you leave some words to explain it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i got it sir, thanks for your attension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1 (@id int)
AS

SELECT name,id 
FROM tablname 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id=@id THEN 0 ELSE id END
```

**Note**: This will work assuming the values of your id columns are always greater then 0.

Comment: waw nice ...its works perfectly..already i had the problem using union but your's  answer is superb

Comment: I suggest you edit your question's title to "How to Show a particular **row** first from a select query". this is probably what confused Tim Schmelter.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: the whole question was confusing. The only hint given was `@id int;`, but nice guess though +1.

Comment: his expected output is ordered by name :) (after the first row)

Comment: @Aツ you are correct, but it's the thought that counts, isn't it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it gives exactly what is your required output.

```
declare @name varchar(10)
set @name = 'c'

create table #temp (id int ,name varchar(10))

insert into #temp(id,name) values(1,'i')
insert into #temp(id,name) values(2,'a')
insert into #temp(id,name) values(3,'b')
insert into #temp(id,name) values(7,'c')
insert into #temp(id,name) values(9,'h')

Select name,id from #temp ORDER BY CASE WHEN name=@name THEN '' ELSE name END

Drop table #temp
```